# Testing creating status is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My test is not successfully creating a guideline and I cannot work out why.

The test in guidelines_controller_test.rb is

```
test "should create guideline when logged in" do
sign_in users(:tester)
assert_difference('Guideline.count') do
  post :create, guideline: { content: @guideline.content, hospital: @guideline.hospital, title: @guideline.title }
end
```

My create action in guidelines_controller.rb is

```
def create
@guideline = Guideline.new(params[:guideline])

respond_to do |format|
  if @guideline.save
    format.html { redirect_to @guideline, notice: 'Guideline was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @guideline, status: :created, location: @guideline }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @guideline.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

when I try to run the test it fails

```
     1) Failure:
test_should_create_guideline_when_logged_in(GuidelinesControllerTest) [test/functional/guidelines_controller_test.rb:36]:
"Guideline.count" didn't change by 1.
<4> expected but was
<3>.
```

and the test.log shows (have tried to copy the relevant bit)

```
 Processing by GuidelinesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"guideline"=>{"content"=>"www.test.com", "hospital"=>"Test Hospital", "title"=>"Test title"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 781720531 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Guideline Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "guidelines" WHERE (LOWER("guidelines"."title") = LOWER('Test title') AND "guidelines"."hospital" = 'Test Hospital') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Rendered guidelines/_form.html.erb (256.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 313ms (Views: 279.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "guidelines" 
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a guideline with a title/hospital combination that already exists.  You got the right chunk of the log - this line:

```
Guideline Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "guidelines" WHERE [...]
```

is Rails making sure that no duplicate guideline already exists (you presumably have a "unique" validation in your model).  It finds a match, so it cancels the save transaction:

```
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

Change the title and/or hospital you're trying to insert, and it should go through just fine.

**Edit:**

Based on our conversation in the comments, I think the problem is as follows:  You're initializing `@guideline` with `@guideline = guidelines(:one)`, which loads the guideline named "one" that you defined in your fixtures file.

However, when you start running tests in Rails, it loads all of the fixtures into the test DB automatically.  So when you try to make a new guideline with the attributes from `@guideline`, you're *guaranteed* to get a duplicate!

The simplest way around this is to define the new attributes in-line in your test code:

```
post :create, guideline: {
    content:  "This is my new content!",
    hospital: "Some Random Hospital",
    title:    "Some Random Title"
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This must be on the right track, but even changing the guideline properties gives the same result 'Parameters: {"guideline"=>{"content"=>"new content", "hospital"=>"new hospital", "title"=>"new title"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 781720531 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Guideline Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "guidelines" WHERE (LOWER("guidelines"."title") = LOWER('new title') AND "guidelines"."hospital" = 'new hospital') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1'

Comment: @user1109434 - Hm.  Are you sure these pairs don't already exist?  That still seems like the best explanation for what's happening...  "New Whatever" is still pretty generic, and likely to have been used before.  Try something bizarre - say a guideline named "Cheddar" for a hospital called "Fred".  I can guarantee _that's_ not in your DB already!

Comment: I'm sure they don't exist.  I can change the values for 'one:' in guidelines.yml and get the same message.  Could it be to do with other tests running on guidelines_controller.rb?  I have another test before it which also runs :create.  At the top of the guidelines_controller_test.rb I have 'setup do
    @guideline = guidelines(:one)
  end'  So maybe the first test is creating guideline(:one) which is why when it tries to run this test it says the guideline already exists?

Comment: actually ignore my previous comment - the :create before doesn't create a guideline, it's 'test "should be logged in to post a guideline" do
    post :create, guideline: { content: "Hello, world"}
    assert_response :redirect
    assert_redirected_to new_user_session_path

  end'

Comment: @user1109434 - I think I figured it out.  See my edit above - it was a bit long for a comment.

Comment: I appreciate your persistence!  Actually this doesn't work either.  For some reason it's saying it exists even when it seems to be completely new content.  Is there another reason why this would be?

Comment: Ok, have tried removing all my validation and the test passes, so this must be the root of the problem.

Comment: @user1109434 - Hard to say - it could be that the my version is passing the uniqueness check but failing some other validation...

Comment: hooray, I am getting closer.  The validations that are causing problems are 'validates_uniqueness_of :title, :scope => :hospital, :case_sensitive => false, :message => "There is already a guideline by this title for this hospital"

validates :user_id, presence: true'